# Position of adverbs in relation to the objects of a sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

Although the placement of adverbs doesn't pose a problem to me anymore, I sometimes find myself wondering which of the two options will sound more natural to a native ear.

> 1a) Brad Pitt slowly walked past Angelina Jolie.
>
> 1b) Brad Pitt walked past Angelina Jolie slowly.
>
> 2b) He loudly pounded on the door.
>
> 2a) He pounded on the door loudly.

EDIT:
Or maybe it's the third option that sounds more idiomatic?

> 1c) Brad Pitt walked slowly past Angelina Jolie.
>
> 2c) He pounded loudly on the door.

Comment: For the first, neither sounds idiomatic to me. Instead, I'd say: _Brad Pitt walked slowly past Angelina Jolie._ For second, the same. Instead of either of your options, I'd say _He pounded loudly on the door._

Comment: Ditto and ditto.